# Can I generalize over class constraints in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In my application I have a type definition that looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

class C a where

data A = forall a. C a => A { unA :: a }
```

I most definitely want the kind signature `A :: Type`.

I would like to generalize over the class constraint, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}

import Data.Kind (Type, Constraint)

class C a where

data A' (c :: Type -> Constraint) where
  A' :: forall a. c a => { unA :: a } -> A' c

type A = A' C
```

Note that `A` should be isomorphic to the `A` as defined in the beginning.

However GHC (8.6.5) rejects the generalized definition:

```
generalize.hs:11:19: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘c’
   |
11 |   A' :: forall a. c a => { unA :: a } -> A' c
   |                   ^

generalize.hs:11:45: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘c’
   |
11 |   A' :: forall a. c a => { unA :: a } -> A' c
   |                                             ^
```

I don't understand the error, since I did enable `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Am I missing something obvious, or is what I'm trying to do not possible? If so, why not?

Comment: The type variables bound in the data definition are not visible in the definition of the constructors. Change it to `A' :: forall c a. c a => { unA :: a } -> A' c`

Comment: Also note that this can be made into a newtype!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i do want `A'` to be of kind `A' :: Constraint -> Type` though. with your suggestion it would be seem to be of kind `A' :: Type`, right?

Comment: @sara I ended up writing your comments into an answer, it probably makes more sense than try to answer it in the comments

Comment: @Cubic that's fine, I'm on a phone right now, so not really set up for writing a good full answer with formatting and stuff anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got it almost right, what you want is

```
data HasConstraint (c :: Type -> Constraint) where
  Pack :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) a . c a => { unPack :: a } -> HasConstraint c
```

so you have to include `c` as inside your constructor type signature as well because it's completely separate from the data declaration for GADTs.

I imagine you'd want to use it like this:

```
instance Show (HasConstraint Show) where show (Pack x) = show x
show (Pack 10 :: HasConstraint Show) -- => "10"
```

You could also write

```
withPacked :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) b. (forall a. c a => a -> b) -> HasConstraint c -> b
withPacked f (Pack x) = f x
withPacked @Show show (Pack 10) -- => "10"
```

I'm not sure if there's much else you can do with this though.

---

(Note that the "getter" `unPack` here actually isn't usable with GADTs either, you'll always have to pattern match on the constructor if you want to actually unpack things).

Comment: the unusability of `unPack` is big bummer though

Comment: @BjörnGohla That just comes with the territory because the type signature of `unPack` would have to depend on the exact constructor used - that's why I showed you the `withPacked` function which, like I said, pretty much encapsulates the only useful thing you can do with this datatype.